# Unable to find inherited method for function ‘crop’ for signature ‘"numeric" using R

Tags: raster, clip, rgdal

I'm trying to iterate a crop and then a resampling process by using a for loop but I've faced some problems because I'd obtain an error message. Below is my code, then the error message

```
#find all tifs in your directory
dir<-"E:\\Proyecto PM2.5\\2_PM_2.5_Processing\\Test"

#get a list of all files with .tif in the name in the directory
files<-list.files(pattern='.tif', full.names = TRUE)

# raster with the expected extent
d <- raster("E:\\Proyecto PM2.5\\3_PM_2.5_Entrega\\temporal\\Raster_D.tif")

#raster with the expected characteristics: extension, cellsize, number of pixels
r_ref <- raster("E:\\Proyecto PM2.5\\3_PM_2.5_Entrega\\temporal\\Raster_C.tif",crs="+init=epsg:32614")


for (i in 1:length(files)){
  r <- raster(files[i])
  rq <- crop(r[i],d)
  rp <- raster::resample(rq[i],r_ref,
                 method = "bilinear",
                 filename = file.path ("./res", files[i]),
                 format = "raster",
                 overwrite = TRUE)
}
```

By running this I obtain the following error:

```
Error in (function (classes, fdef, mtable)  : 
  unable to find an inherited method for function ‘crop’ for signature ‘"numeric"’
```

I've read that could be related to that I'm applying an S4 method to a not supported object, but looking into the class for *r* I obtain this:

```
[1] "RasterLayer"
attr(,"package")
[1] "raster"
```

How do I solve this error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you are trying to apply a list index to objects that are not lists.

In your code you loop over the list of files like this:

```
for (i in 1:length(files)){
  r <- raster(files[i])
  rq <- crop(r[i],d)
  rp <- raster::resample(rq[i],r_re
```

files[i] is correct, because files is a list.  As best as I can tell, the next two lines, r[i] and rq[i], are not lists, they are individual objects taken from the list of files.

Comment: Thank @jgm_GIS, you're completely right, by excluding *[i]* the code ran properly. I will take into consideration this logic for future loops.